# CSS is not applying to image

Tags: html, css

Trying to get CSS to apply to an image that is contained as below (I have removed other HTML code to simplify it):

```
<div class="wrap">
 <main>
   <article>
     <img src="images/forest.jpeg" width="800px">
   </article>
 </main>
</div>
```

Currently trying to apply CSS as follows:

```
.wrap img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: What output you want. Its already applied to img

Comment: It was working.

Comment: `max-width` doesn't really make a lot for the image, it's just like a condition that it's width should not exceed `100%`. If you're trying to make the img's width to `100%`, you must put `width:100%`, otherwise, tell us what are you expecting to see, and what are you seeing.

Comment: `100%` of what exactly?

Comment: Lets scratch the `max-width`. I am also trying `border-radius` and that does not seem to apply to the image either?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look css does appy here

```css
.wrap img{
  height: 400px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
 <main>
   <article>
     <img src="http://sd.keepcalm-o-matic.co.uk/i-w600/keep-calm-400-level-loading-1.jpg" />
   </article>
 </main>
</div>
```

Comment: It still doesn't seem to apply to my image. If it helps `.wrap` is flex and so it `main` and `article`

Comment: @design-wizard I tried with flex and it works for me too, is ur css file linked  properly to ur html, have u checked that via inspect element

Comment: All my other styles work fine its just its not applying for that specific img.

Comment: well if it works here it should work everywhere, there might be some other css overwriting ur css try with `!important` and see, you should inspect elemtn ur code and see whats d issue there, hope it helps @design-wizard

Comment: Just figured it out. It was a linking issue due to me moving around css files. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

Because inline css has higher priority than others. Change it like:

```
<img src="images/forest.jpeg">

.wrap img {
   width:800px;
   max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick Fix

```
.wrap > main > article > img{max-width: 100% !important;}
```

Comment: It is not going to work, because .wrap is not an immediate parent of img in his case.

Comment: Still, it's enough to do just .wrap img { //style }, no need for pseudo selector.